# Guitar amplifier emits a continuous beep, which pitch vary depending on "bass" and "gain" knobs. Finding what's wrong in the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, repair, guitar-amplifier

I have an old transistor (EDIT: not transistor, but OP, from comments) guitar amp, a ***Laney Session 45 Reverb***. I couldn't find any schematics online unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be a very popular model. I got it second-hand and it worked fine for a while, but suddenly, each time I power it, it emits a continuous, loud beep. The characteristics of the beep are the following:

- Loudness varies with volume knobs, from silent to very loud.
- Reverb, treble, frequency controls from the EQ don't seem to alter the beep
- I tried taking away the amovible spring reverb and the behavior is the exact same
- Overdrive channel switch and overdrive volume seem to affect the beep (but it's hard to tell since it's a continuous beep)
- I think guitar signal still goes through the amp, but I'm not sure because the beep is so loud I can't hear it
- **when I turn the bass or the gain knobs, the beep varies wildly in pitch**. It goes from "eeeeeeee" to "eeewooowiieewooeiiwiee", like a synthesizer. It can go fairly low to very high. Low bass or low gain makes the beep low, high bass or high gain make it high. The gain knob seems to affect the pitch a bit less than the bass knob.

I am new to electronics so I didn't completely take it apart yet, I just exposed the circuit boards (there are two) and blew air to clean them. They are covered in a slightly greasy or sticky substance, and there are a few cables that have been obviously re-soldered. My coworker had a look at the boards and said that the greasiness probably came from a tropicalizing spray that aged poorly; and that the problem seems to come from a broken component, not a circuit short. I took a multimeter and tested the continuity of connections that seemed artsanal or re-made. Apparently, no short.

Basically, my amp turned into a synthesizer. Where does that beep come from? Is it symptomatic of a broken/dead component? Is there an easy fix to it?

[EDIT: additional pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZBiA.jpg). They show both boards (the back one is hard to photograph).

[image: Front of the amp with diagnosis on each knob]
[image: Circuit board of the amp]

Labelled with chips
[image]

- [LF351 Op Amp](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/ee/a4/60/e6/50/fb/41/3b/CD00000453.pdf/files/CD00000453.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000453.pdf)
- [LF353 Dual Op Amp](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf353-n.pdf)
- [CD4069 Hex Inverter](https://www.silicon-ark.co.uk/datasheets/cd4069UBcn-datasheet-national-semiconductor.pdf)
- [CD4066 Quad Bilateral Switch](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf)

Comment: That sounds like it could be some form of positive feedback in the amplifier (like what happens if you hold a microphone up to a speaker). Do you have any schematics of the amplifier? It looks fairly easy to reverse engineer.

Comment: Very approximately what frequency is the "beep"?

Comment: It is clear to me that you have some _unwanted_ feedback in the amplification section. I would start by cleaning all pots with Deoxit or a similar electronics cleaner. Just make sure it is suitable for carbon pots otherwise you might damage them. It is very likely that you will have to replace all electrolytics as they seem original and 
 this type of capacitor degrades over time. If you feel comfortable with soldering, retouch all solder joints too and do not forget to use plenty of flux.

Comment: @jonathanjo too add to this, C. Crt can use an app called _Spectroid_ (available for Android and iOS). A very useful tool for audio analysis

Comment: I see ICs, not transistors. They'll be op amps. My guess is one of them has died.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the quick feedback. So, @Hearth, I couldn't find any schematics online, googling "Laney session 45 reverb schematics" or "diagram" or "blueprint" doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jonathanjo, I'm currently installing Spectroid to test it. But by ear, I would say the pitch changes from ~160 to ~1000 Hz.

Comment: @DanielMelendrez, you might be right. I will order all that. But my coworker said "yep, a component is missing", so i have this lead! Annoyingly, he left for vacation...

Comment: Check out [Fazio Electric](https://www.youtube.com/c/FazioElectric)'s videos of exotic amp repair; could be helpful.

Comment: Can I suggest a crisp photo so we can read the part numbers?

Comment: @IanBland, as a noob, I thought there were only two kinds of amps: tube and transistors, so TIL. Can I test an IC with a multimeter? EDIT: [seems like I can](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9Lu5Z_yKZ0). I'll do it later

Comment: @rdtsc, I will, thanks. I'm at work so in a few hours,

Comment: @jonathanjo I will take one soon, I'm at work so I need a little while but I wll take a better pic

Comment: @C.Crt That's why I mentioned reverse engineering. Trace out the circuit, identify all the ICs you can, and make a schematic yourself. This doesn't look like a very complicated circuit.

Comment: @C.Crt when you take the pic, take a series of good closeups in focus, front and back.

Comment: Hard to tell, did it start exhibiting this behavior more and more or did it go from working to beeping one day?

Comment: @winny it went from working to beeping in one day! It worked, then I didn't use it for a few months (it wasn't stored in a particularly damp place or whatever), then I plugged it and it beeped.

Comment: @jonathanjo I took more pictures! They are not fantastic because my phone quality is not so crisp and it was hard to fit it in there. But still, [there](https://imgur.com/a/XoFs3Ci).

Comment: Ah! Slowly degrading/increase in beep would hint to a capacitor going bad. This is something else.

Comment: So wait, did it go from working to beeping in one day, or in several months of non-use?

Comment: @Hearth I'd say several months of non-use. It's a bit distant. It went like that: 1. I buy the amp, 2. I use it, 3. I stop using it, 4. Months pass and I try to use it but it beeps, 5. I dn't loko at it for a long while, 6. I get back to it, problem persists, I make this post.

Comment: I fix alotta guitar amps.   Without a schematic this will be difficult for sure.  What I'd suggest is the CHOPSTICK TEST.   9 times out of 10, with an old PCB amp, it turns out to be a wonky solder joint on some component.  With the amp powered on, poke EVERYTHING with a wooden stick (i.e. a chopstick!) and see if you can identify some component that magically makes the beep stop when you touch it.   Obviously if you find one, resolder it.

Comment: Hi everyone, I haven't been able to get back to it yet, but your help has been fantastic. Thank you all for your comments and ideas. Big thanks to @jonathanjo for the high quality edit.

Answer (score 4):

> *Is there an easy fix to it?*

Fault finding on this circuit should be easy; you have a pre-amp circuit board and, it appears you have a power amp circuit board set deeper into the picture and in the middle. Disconnect the **signal** input (from the pre-amp) to the power amp and see if the noise goes away. If it does then the problem is in the pre-amp.

Quite possibly it's an electrolytic capacitor that has gone bad/dry and, whilst it should normally smooth a supply rail in the pre-amp it no longer does thus, positive feedback via the power rails is a strong candidate.

Answer (score 3):

Andy aka suggested I raise this to an answer, although it's only a guess. There have been many novel approaches to getting a good distortion sound in solid state amplifiers, and I strongly suspect that the 4069 hex inverter is being used outside its "manufacturer intended" role (hex inverter) as the distortion/drive circuit. CMOS chips can turn up in all sorts of weird configurations like this.

I would have a look and see if it is part of the analogue circuit (I may be wrong, it may just be some kind of control for the analogue switch 4066) and if  it is, I would try swapping it out. CMOS is static sensitive and it may have been damaged.

Take static precautions when handling a replacement IC.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible that one of the components has become [**microphonic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphonics) . To Quote the Wikipedia article

> Guitar amplifiers that incorporate the electronic chassis into the
> same cabinet as the speaker are susceptible to microphonics.

I would suggest that you use a piece of soft plastic (insulating) to go round the boards and gently tap each component. If any are microphonic you will hear a noise in the speaker.